# Загрузка файлов через TWebBrowser [закрыт]

Tags: delphi

Есть форма загрузки файлов:

```
<input class="file" id='textinput' type=file name=uploads_0 id=attachId0 size=60 onchange="checkUploadFile(this);" style="width: 479px">
```

Я хочу отправить свой файл: нахожу нужный мне элемент по типу и изменяю значение:

```
for i:=0 to WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.forms.Length -1 do
      begin
      FormItem:=WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.forms.Item(i);
      for j:=0 to FormItem.Length -1 do
            if FormItem.Item(j).type ='file' then FormItem.Item(j).filename:='D:\1.jpg';
      end;
```

Но ничего не происходит, в отличии от обычных "`input type=text`". Почему?

**Может быть, есть другие способы загрузки файлов?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это один из аспектов браузерной защиты персональных данных.
Представьте ситуацию, в которой JavaScript любого сайта мог бы в автоматическом режиме заполнять такие input-ы и аплоадить их себе на сервер. А в файлах, к примеру, ключи от вебмани!
TWebBrowser c HTML работает через DOM (как и JavaScript). Поэтому ничего не получится.

Имеет смысл копать в сторону прямой отправки post-запроса с файлом на сервер.

Comment: не совсем понял причем тут защита, если я работаю из браузера, а не скрипта на другом сайте

Comment: Тем не менее @KiTE прав) Просто запрещено изменять вручную значение `<input type="file" />`, не важно, с помощью чего.

Comment: ясно, буду шаманить с нажатиями.

Comment: Лучше ручной POST, правда. Надежнее.

Comment: тогда надо ещё все параметры отследить: куки, скрытые поля и тд.
не, я напрямую сделаю, как обычно (: